# What iPhone apps can't you live without?

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch, applications

What are your "must-have" iPhone or iPod touch apps—the ones you can't live without? (Figuratively speaking, I hope.) Please omit apps that come pre-installed.

#### Rules

- **One** app per answer.
- Use this format for the first two lines of your answer:
  **`## [app name](link to website)`**
  **`[App Store](link to appstore)`**
- Include short **description**.
- **Check for duplicates** before adding new answers.
- If you find a duplicate, vote it down and encourage its poster to upvote the original entry instead (and remove the dupe).

Please exclude iPad-only apps from here; there's [*Great iPad Apps*](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1286/great-ipad-apps) for those.

**Disclaimer**: I know this type of question is controversial. However, great many people do find that *properly implemented and curated* CW polls can be useful. (If you are one of those who do *not*, could you simply consider ignoring this?)

Comment: Why do people insist on downvoting in these types of questions. That's really in poor taste, I think. If you don't like something, just leave it alone.

Comment: Hmm.. the price probably depends on the Apple store (e.g. for me prices show in Euros) Which price should we note?

Comment: @Juan: yes, prices vary and are in different currencies. I think the most "universal" for our purposes is USD; you can check the US$ prices for each app at http://appshopper.com.

Over here we use the euro too, and I personally chose to put both USD and EUR prices e.g. in [this answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/706/iphone-apps-you-cant-live-without/708#708).

Comment: It's a bit silly to list prices here as they change pretty regularly. If somebody reads the description in the answer and is compelled to buy it, they can click through to the app store to see what the current price is.

Comment: @bpapa: Fair point. Then again, it may have some value that readers can see *right away* whether an app is free or its (ballpark) cost.

Comment: @Jonik thanks for formatting the answers properly, and sorry I didn't do it myself at first. Nice job! :)

Comment: If your interested in task automation, I created a cool app called "Actions - Fast forward everyday tasks". You can download it on the App Store: https://itunes.apple.com/app/id993488068

Answer (score 53):

### [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/iphoneapp)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dropbox/id327630330)

Conveniently access files in your [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) on the go.

Comment: Out of all 40 apps listed here before my contribution, this is the only one I would include as "iphone app I can't live without".

Answer (score 38):

### [Twitter](http://blog.twitter.com/2010/05/twitter-for-iphone.html)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/twitter/id333903271?mt=8)

The official Twitter client. Previously known as Tweetie 2.

Comment: I used to use TweetDeck, but after trying this (when it was made free and renamed Twitter for iPhone) I haven't gone back. Very smooth, inspired UI.

Comment: Meh, Echofon is much better.

Comment: Unfortunately, recently started to display unremovable promoted tweets. And that can't be disabled.

Answer (score 32):

### [Reeder](http://reederapp.com/)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/reeder/id325502379?mt=8)

Google Reader client.

Comment: Reeder is truly what an RSS reader should be. I wish I could find a desktop counterpart that matched it.

Comment: @Bryson, why you need a mobile RSS reader? Can't you read it from web browser?

Comment: I use the web Google Reader on my iPhone daily and i am not missing much, up to now. What are the main advantages of an app?

Comment: Well, Reeder's interface is much nicer (and cleaner) than that of Google Reader. Also, Reeder supports offline reading.

Comment: @Bryson there's Reeder for Mac. http://madeatgloria.com/brewery/silvio/reeder

Answer (score 32):

### [Instapaper](http://www.instapaper.com/)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/instapaper/id288545208?mt=8)

A simple tool to save web pages for reading later.

Answer (score 31):

### [Remote](http://www.apple.com/itunes/remote/)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/app/remote/id284417350)

Wifi remote control for iTunes music library (or Apple TV). This is made by Apple but doesn't come pre-installed.

(Some have pointed out that Remote's development has [stagnated](http://www.macrumors.com/2010/08/03/apples-flexible-engineering-teams-said-to-operate-like-a-startup/), but personally I don't mind that much, as the app works as great as ever, and all major features are already there.)

Comment: IMHO a very handy, instantaneous way to control music playback at home. Unlike with infrared remotes, walls are not an obstacle. :) When first trying this (some 2 years ago), it was one of those tech "wow" moments.

Comment: They came out with a new version within the last 2 weeks.

Comment: Yeah, they did. Version 2.0 includes e.g. proper [iPad support](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1286/great-ipad-apps/2818#2818) which is really neat.

Answer (score 26):

### [Facebook](http://www.facebook.com/iphone)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/app/facebook/id284882215)

If you're into [Facebook](http://www.facebook.com/), their official iPhone app is pretty good for staying connected with people.

Answer (score 19):

### [Shazam](http://www.shazam.com/music/web/pages/iphone.html)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/shazam/id284993459?mt=8)

Records a few seconds of what you're currently listening to and then shows you information about this song. Shazam is quite old by now, but still an amazing piece of software that's always useful from time to time.

Comment: Can you compare Shazam to SoundHound - which one is better?

Comment: I'm forced to use both: SoundHound is generally better at finding a song. I had many situations where Shazam didn't know a song but SoundHound found it easily. However, SoundHound isn't sensitive enough. As an example it's not possible at all to catch a song from the radio in my office. Shazam on the other hand seems to adapt and can easily record songs also from this same radio.

Comment: SoudHound seems a lot faster than Shazam. Will start to try to match a song even before the full capture. It also identified songs that Shazam didn't. And SoundHound's free version allows unlimited matches, while Shazam allows 5 per month.

Answer (score 15):

### Sleep Cycle alarm clock

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sleep-cycle-alarm-clock/id320606217?mt=8)

An alarm clock that analyzes your sleep patterns (using iPhone accelerometer) and wakes you in the lightest sleep phase.

Comment: Just got this over the weekend, and I'm very impressed. Currently have a pretty bad cold, and I remember waking with coughing fits a few times during the night. Because I was using this app, I could tell what time they were and how long they lasted. It also wakes me at the time I want, and its been easier to wake up, because its not in the middle of a sleep cycle. Pretty cool.

Answer (score 15):

## [1Password](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/1password-pro/id319898689?mt=8)

If you use 1Password on your Mac, the iOS app is quite handy.  It can be linked to a Dropbox account therefore keeping data synchronized between your desktop and iOS device.  There are regular and pro versions available for both iPhone and iPad.

Answer (score 13):

### [Things](http://culturedcode.com/things/iphone/)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/app/things/id284971781)

Task management tool. The todo items can be synced (over wifi) with [OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82/os-x-applications-you-cant-live-without/453#453) and iPad versions.

Comment: Cheaper alternatives exist, but I haven't regretted buying Things (having used it for almost 2 years). I like the simple yet powerful UI.

Answer (score 13):

### [PlainText](http://www.hogbaysoftware.com/products/plaintext)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/plaintext-dropbox-text-editing/id391254385?mt=8)

> Dropbox text editing.
>
> For editing text on iPad & iPhone. PlainText is a simple text editor with a paper-like user interface. Unlike the default Notes app, PlainText allows you to create and organize your documents in folders and sync everything with Dropbox.com. Requires iOS 3.0+

After trying different note-taking apps like [SimpleNote](http://simplenoteapp.com/) and [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com/), I discovered this beauty a few days ago and it immediately replaced the built-in Notes app for me, both on my iPhone and my iPad. It fit my needs perfectly, and is really simple & beautifully designed. YMMV, but it's free to try.

P.S. [Elements](http://www.secondgearsoftware.com/elements/) is a feature-packed alternative with Markdown support and built-in email, but I'm not sure I need those features and it's $4.99.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! Seems to fit my needs pretty well, as I already use Dropbox and often use plain text files for notes. Now I just need to do some Dropbox reorganising to make my stuff show up in this app...

Answer (score 11):

### [SoundHound](http://www.soundhound.com/)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/soundhound/id355554941?mt=8)

SoudHound seems a lot faster than Shazam. Will start to try to match a song even before the full capture. It also identified songs that Shazam didn't. And SoundHound's free version allows unlimited matches, while Shazam allows 5 per month.

Comment: I love it! But I **guess** I could live without it... :P

Answer (score 11):

### [Angry Birds](http://www.angrybirds.com/)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/angry-birds/id343200656?mt=8)

The best game in the app store

Comment: See also: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/683/great-ios-games

Comment: I bought into the angry birds hype, but quickly got over it. Realized it was just a trial and error game with a good physics engine, not exactly my forte. A great time waster nonetheless.

Comment: With people, of any age, who haven't played much games before (or perhaps used iPhone at all), it's fun to load this up and see them quickly learn the game, then become a bit addicted to it.

Answer (score 10):

### [WhatsApp](http://www.whatsapp.com/)

[App Store](http://www.whatsapp.com/appstore/)

WhatsApp Messenger is a smartphone messaging app which allows you to exchange messages with your friends and contacts without having to pay for SMS. WhatsApp Messenger is cross platform and available for iPhone, BlackBerry, Android and Nokia (beta) and yes, those phones can all message each other! To send and receive messages, WhatsApp utilizes your existing smartphone internet data plan: 3G/EDGE (or Wi-Fi when available)

In addition to messaging, iPhone, Android and BlackBerry WhatsApp Messenger users can send each other unlimited images, video and audio media messages.

Answer (score 10):

### [Cydia](http://cydia.saurik.com/)

[Cydia](http://cydia.saurik.com/) (jailbreak required)

Cydia is a software application for iOS that is a graphical front end to APT and the dpkg package management system. It allows a user to browse and download applications for a jailbroken iPhone, iPod Touch or iPad.

[image: cydia-screenshot]

Answer (score 9):

### [Articles](http://www.sophiestication.com/articles)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/app/id317065689?mt=8/)

Best way to read Wikipedia.

Comment: Is this better than the official [Wikipedia app](http://itunes.apple.com/app/wikipedia-mobile/id324715238?mt=8)?

Comment: I would say yes, but this of course is subjective.

Answer (score 8):

### [OmniFocus](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnifocus_for_iphone/)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=284885288&mt=8)

Task management application that uses the [Getting Things Done (GTD)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getting_Things_Done) organizational method. Also available for [Mac](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnifocus/) and [iPad](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnifocus-ipad/).

Answer (score 8):

### [Simplenote](http://simplenoteapp.com/)

Note-taking in a better interface than the default Notes application (no Marker Felt) and notes are synched to a server for easy backups and viewing elsewhere.

Comment: This is awesome. There's an OS X app called Notational Velocity (that's also open source) that also syncs with Simplenote, and can be set to store notes in my Dropbox. This keeps my notes backed up locally, in the cloud, and in Simplenote's server as well as being editable across any platform. Such a great app/service.

Answer (score 8):

### [Spotify](http://www.spotify.com/mobile/iphone/)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/app/spotify/id324684580)

For listening to music off the internet (directly on wifi/3G or via offline playlists).

**NB**: Spotify is only available in [certain countries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spotify#Geographic_availability), and [Spotify Premium](http://www.spotify.com/get-spotify/premium/) (€9.99 or £9.99 per month) is needed to use the iPhone app.

Now with iOS 4 + iPhone 4 (unlike with my unjailbroken iPhone 3G earlier) the experience is really good, as you get background play and ability to use normal iPod playback controls (e.g. the headphone remote). In other words, it's similar to using the built-in iPod app, except that you have approximately 10 million tracks available at your fingertips.

Comment: Aren't *most* apps only available in certain countries?  I've tried to install Japanese apps on my American iPod, and been rejected by iTunes as needing an AppleID/iTunes account with a mailing address in Japan for that.

Answer (score 8):

### [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/features/iphone/)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/imdb-movies-tv/id342792525?mt=8)

iPhone app for the largest movie database website IMDb

Answer (score 7):

### [instagr.am](http://instagr.am//)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/app/instagram/id389801252) (free)

It’s a fast, beautiful and fun way to share your life with friends through a series of pictures. Snap a photo with your iPhone, choose a filter to transform the look and feel, send to Facebook, Twitter or Flickr – it’s all as easy as pie. It’s photo sharing, reinvented.

Simple idea, brillantly executed.

Answer (score 6):

### [Dictionary.com](http://www.reference.com/apps/iphone)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/app/dictionary-com-dictionary/id308750436)

Comprehensive, yet free, dictionary & thesaurus. Key features:

- All word definitions come with the app—no internet connection needed
- Decent UI with autocomplete (no need to type in the whole word)
- Audio pronunciations (internet connection required for this)

Answer (score 6):

### [Adobe Photoshop Express](http://mobile.photoshop.com/)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/adobe-photoshop-express/id331975235?mt=8)

Great little mobile photo editor!

Comment: Annoyed that it doesn't let me do scaling to make images smaller for sending MMS, but it's good for the couple limited things it does.

Answer (score 6):

### [Cut the Rope](http://www.chillingo.com/sku.htm?sid=344)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cut-the-rope/id380293530) ($0.99)

The best game in the app store

Answer (score 6):

### [Pandora Radio](http://www.pandora.com/on-the-iphone)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pandora-radio/id284035177?mt=8) (free)

Everyone probably knows about Pandora Radio by now.  Put in a favorite artist and it helps you locate similar artists.  It's helped me find many new bands.

Answer (score 5):

### Trainyard

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/trainyard/id348719156?mt=8) ($0.99 USD)

A great puzzle game with tons of levels. Kept me playing for days, and I've still been unable to beat a couple levels after a couple months of having the app.  There is also a free version. Intuitive, fun, and brain exercising.

Answer (score 5):

### [Tweetbot By Tapbots](http://tapbots.com/software/tweetbot/)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id428851691?mt=8) (Price: $2.99)

**Description**

Tweetbot is a full-featured iPhone (and iPod touch) Twitter client with a lot of personality. Whether it’s the meticulously-crafted interface, sounds & animation, or features like multiple timelines & smart gestures, there’s a lot to love about Tweetbot.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

### [Remember The Milk](http://www.rememberthemilk.com)

[App Store](http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=293561396&mt=8)

The best way to manage your tasks.

Comment: RTM is actually a paid app - it's free to download but after 2 weeks it only works with a paid account on the RTM website!

Comment: not anymore. the app is now free (if you want advanced notifications features, then you need the paid account)

Answer (score 4):

### [Pulse](http://www.alphonsolabs.com)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pulse-news-mini/id377594176?mt=8)

[Reeder](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/706/iphone-apps-you-cant-live-without/721#721) is the best RSS reader for Google Reader. But Pulse is much nicer to randomly read various feeds.

Comment: I like it, but I find it crashes a lot for me. Anyone else?

Answer (score 4):

### [Pocket](http://getpocket.com/)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/read-it-later-pro/id309601447?mt=8)

Pocket lets you save webpages to read later, **even without an internet connection**. Ideal for those who have iPod touch but don't have access to Wifi. Also while travelling in subway, where 3g always goes haywire.

Answer (score 4):

### [Doodle Jump](http://www.limasky.com/)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/doodle-jump-be-warned-insanely/id307727765?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D2)

Doodle Jump™ is THE MOST ADDICTIVE GAME on the App Store. Enough said :)

Comment: See also: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/683/great-ios-games

Answer (score 4):

### [Soulver](http://www.acqualia.com/soulver/iphone/)

App Store ($2.99)

Soulver is by far the most useful calculator app in the App Store. It's a much easier and more powerful way to work with numbers over a normal calculator. Embed text with your calculations to make it easier to see the problem you are solving. You can easily go back and make a change earlier in the calculation and have everything updated, similar to a spreadsheet. You can use several lines and reference previous lines in your calculations allowing yourself to split up long equations or even reuse parts to see different results. These can all be saved on separate sheets so it's easy to go back and reference them later. You'll never go back to a normal calculator again.

(Sorry, will only let me post one hyper link)

Answer (score 4):

### [Flipboard](http://flipboard.com/)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/flipboard/id358801284?mt=8)

the best newsreader and social hub

Answer (score 3):

### [Echofon](http://www.echofon.com/twitter/iphone/)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/app/echofon-for-twitter/id286756410?mt=8) (free)
[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/echofon-pro-for-twitter/id315577859?mt=8) ($4.99)

A great twitter client with [synchronization](http://www.echofon.com/push-sync-guide.html) between the [desktop version for Mac](http://www.echofon.com/twitter/mac/) and the [Firefox extension](http://www.echofon.com/twitter/firefox/)

Comment: Can you name anything specific that make it better than the official Twitter app? (I'm pretty happy with that one.)

Comment: @Jonik: It's just designed much better and easier to read tweets. You can click links without having to click the tweet and loading it first. Plus on the trending topics you can see explanations, which I like.

Comment: I found Echofon to be the best Twitter app until the official one came along, and even then I kept it for notifications, but now that the official Twitter app has those, the only place  Echofon wins out on is trending topics, explanations as mentioned above and IIRC you were able to select a region for the trending topics. However I've uninstalled it and just use the offical app now.

Answer (score 3):

### [Viber](http://www.viber.com/)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/app/viber-free-phone-calls/id382617920)

**Viber** is a MUST-HAVE app. Lets you make and get free calls over 3G or Wifi even the app is not running. Notifies you when there is a call for you. Also gets your contact list and notifies when a friend installs VIBER. Sound quality is amazing even on 3G. I am talking to my best buddy living in Switzerland freely via Wifi from Turkey. And VIBER is a **FREE** app.

Comment: "...free..." Which brings up the question, how do they make money?

Answer (score 3):

### [Mobile Mouse](http://mobilemouse.com/)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/air-mouse-pro-remote-trackpad/id289616509?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D6) (1.99$)

Mobile Mouse instantly transforms your iPhone or iPod touch into an in air, wireless remote for your computer! Sit back and use this remote to surf the web, browse your photo library or control your music player from the comfort of your couch.

I use an old mac-mini as a Media Center and the combi *Remote+Mobile Mouse* apps is gold!

Comment: awesome app1 writing with it now ;)

Comment: you should try **JumiOne**, tho I think it's still windows only.

Answer (score 3):

### [Calvetica](http://calvetica.com/)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/calvetica-sync-google-calendar/id385862462?mt=8) ($2.99)

A beautiful, minimal calendar app without peer.

Just go look. I defy you to *not* become more efficient with your calendar use.

Answer (score 3):

### [AppShopper](http://appshopper.com/iphone/)

[App store](http://itunes.apple.com/app/appshopper/id387037496?mt=8) (free)

You can keep a list of apps you want, and it will let you know when they drop in price.

Answer (score 3):

### [Instacast](http://vemedio.com/products/instacast)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/instacast/id420368235?mt=8) ($1.99)

It's the best Podcast-App in the AppStore, and handles Podcast much better than iTunes.

- Download all Podcasts; automatically and in the background
- Stream Podcast over Edge, 3G or WiFi
- Continue where you left off
- Support for iCloud

Answer (score 2):

### [ComicBookLover](http://www.bitcartel.com/comicbooklover/)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/comicbooklover/id351623583?mt=8) (free)

Read .cbr and .cbz format comic books. All sorts of transfer options, including iTunes sync. Good, intuitive page flipping. Great in combination with the desktop version, which allows you to add all sorts of metadata to maintain your collection.

Works best on the iPhone's 4 retina display - no need to zoom!

Answer (score 2):

### [MyWi](http://www.intelliborn.com/mywi.html)

(Not avaiable in app store; [jailbreak required](http://www.iphonefreak.com/2009/09/apps-that-make-me-willing-to-jailbreak-mywi.html).)

Turns your iPhone into a wifi hotspot. Just great!

Answer (score 1):

### [Server Remote](http://lesscode.co.nz/iphone/server-remote)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=331433974) ($3.99)

Simple app to monitor servers, including uptime, running commands, load levels, and memory. Really worth it.

Answer (score 1):

### [Safety Light](http://safetylightapp.com/)

When it comes to flashlight apps, you get what you pay for. I've tried a number of these, and the interface and technical capabilities are just right. Much, much better than the free ones. Also, it somehow manages to get the screen super-bright, lighting up an entire room without draining the battery like the new LED-using apps that have flooded the App Store. No battery warning to is this one.

Answer (score 1):

### [Byline](http://www.phantomfish.com/byline.html)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/app/byline/id284946773) ($4.99 / 3.99 €)
[App Store (Byline Free)](http://itunes.apple.com/app/byline-free/id375551811) (free; with ads)

Google Reader on the go. Byline will automatically bring you new content, putting thousands of RSS and Atom feeds at your fingertips. Even when you have no internet connection, Byline gives you instant access to complete web pages. It automatically analyses your feeds so that it can cache the ones with truncated content. This means all your news is there in full when you’re offline, and blazing fast to load when you’re online to boot.

Answer (score 1):

### [MoneyBook](http://moneybookapp.com)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/moneybook/id337954399?mt=8) ($2.99)

Great app to track and manage finances.

Answer (score 1):

### [Prizmo for iPhone](http://www.creaceed.com/prizmo/iphone)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/prizmo/id366791896?mt=8) ($9.99)

Though it is expensive (compared to other apps that is), this is OCR done right. Works great to capture some texts, quicker than using a scanner and can also be used to import business cards.

Answer (score 1):

### [StreamToMe](http://projectswithlove.com/streamtome)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/streamtome/id325327899?mt=8) ($2.99)

Streams almost any video or music from your Mac or PC to the iPhone and iPad. The Mac/PC is converting the source file on the fly. Playback generally starts after 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

### [Profanity](http://www.appygolucky.co.uk/profanity/)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/profanity/id320383256?mt=8) ($0.99 / £0.59)

The best (and only) profanity generator in the App store. Always useful in the pub. Otherwise completely pointless but great fun.

Answer (score 1):

### [Wikipanion](http://www.wikipanion.net/)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wikipanion/id288349436?mt=8) (free)

Probably the best Wikipedia app in the AppStore. Easy navigation, nice article formatting, very fast.

Comment: [Articles](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/706/iphone-apps-you-cant-live-without/1553#1553) is probably slightly better, but out of the free Wikipedia apps, yes, Wikipanion is the best.

Comment: There is also the new official wikipedia App, although having used both I'd be hard pushed to say which is better out of the official app and Wikipanion.

Answer (score 1):

### [GoodReader for iPhone](http://www.goodiware.com/goodreader.html)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/app/id306277111?mt=8) ($2.99)

Super-robust PDF reader with advanced reading, annotating, markup and highlighting capabilities, excellent file manager, TXT file reader and editor, audio/video player, Safari-like viewer for MS Office and iWorks files.

This is a great app for any documents organizer and good PDF reader. It also can unzip the zip files, as it's not natively handled by iOS. I use it everyday. It used to sell $0.99, but now they increased price.

Comment: Update: It's now a universal app, so it works on both iPhone and iPad!

Answer (score 1):

### [Snappy](http://www.redmondpie.com/snappy-the-fastest-camera-app-for-jailbroken-iphone-9140131/)

Enable using the camera from anywhere, even while screen locked. Just configure how to activate it (mine is double tap the lock button) and take photos really, really fast. Also configure the volume button to act as a shutter. It has few more great features such as being able to take one photo after the other really quickly, proper geolocation and camera meta data.
This apps is for jailbroken phones only.

Answer (score 1):

### [PCalc](http://www.pcalc.com/iphone/)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/app/pcalc-rpn-calculator/id284666222?mt=8) ($9.99)

My favourite calculator on iOS. The best feature is the optional [RPN mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation), but it's chockers with other goodies, a very capable tool. I've found it indispensable at university—unfortunately I still have to borrow a graphics calculator for officially invigilated exams, but when there's an in-class test sprung upon me, someone asks me to help them, or even in casual conversation when a question beyond my horrifically meagre arithmetical abilities arises, PCalc is great. It doesn't handle actual graphing, & it still handles statistics in the same horrifically bad way every physical calculator since the old HPs has, but the rest is fine: different notations, bases, button layouts, unit conversions, etc., & the (distressingly un-)usual logarithmic, hyperbolic, trigonometric et al. functions. A dedicated unit from TI, HP or Casio will completely outstrip PCalc but it makes the anaemic built-in calculator look like a child's toy.

Answer (score 1):

### [Anki](http://ankisrs.net/docs/AnkiMobile.html)

Anki is software to help make it easier to remember things. It uses spaced repetition technology to make sure you only see the items you are having trouble remembering and the things you do remember you see less often. I can't imagine studying without it anymore. In particular it's been a huge help studying languages and I highly recommend it. The iPhone app is a companion to the desktop software and syncs through their servers. The desktop application is free, but if you find it useful the iPhone app is invaluable to studying on the go.

Answer (score 1):

### [WiFi2HiFi](http://www.wifi2hifi.com/)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/wifi2hifi/id417409424?mt=8) (USD $3.99)

Stream Grooveshark, Spotify, Pandora or any other audio player from the computer to the iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

### [Pastebot](http://tapbots.com/software/pastebot/)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/app/id344614116) ($3.99/€2.99)

Together with its companion Mac application, let's you copy/paste from Mac to iPhone. Really handy. It also keeps clipboard data in your iPhone (example: you can copy an image from a website and keep it in Pastebot)

Answer (score 1):

### [TextExpander](http://www.smilesoftware.com/TextExpander/touch/index.html)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=326180690&mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D6) ($4.99)

Create shorthand strings which expand into more complex statements. For instance, you can create a snippet such that typing ssig expands to

> Regards,
>
> John Doe
>
> 123 Sesame St.
>
> Anywhere, USA 12345
>
> foo@bar.com

Snippets can include variable values, and quite a few other niceties. Many popular apps also support TextExpander, a list of which appears [here](http://www.smilesoftware.com/TextExpander/touch/apps/). This is really useful for reducing the amount of typing repetitive or common phrases.

Answer (score 1):

## [Prompt](http://www.panic.com/prompt/support.html)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/prompt/id421507115?mt=8) ($7.99)

Allows you to SSH from any iOS device. I find it indispensable for doing C++ homework.

Answer (score 0):

### [Major League Baseball (MLB.com)](http://mlb.mlb.com/mobile/iphone/)

Better than reading the sports page.

Answer (score 0):

### [Colorendar](http://app.birnimal.net/en/iphoneapp/colorendar)

([$0.99](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/colorendar/id344487402?mt=8))

Simple calendar app that let's you create a "color diary." Also shows you phases of the moon.

Answer (score 0):

### [OPlayer](http://olimsoft.wordpress.com/category/software/)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/oplayer/id344784375?mt=8) (€2,39)
[App Store, Lite version](http://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/oplayer-lite/id385907472?mt=8) (Free)

Plays almost every kind of video format, without having to transcode first. Transfer via iTunes sync or stream right from a web server. There's also an iPad version.

Answer (score 0):

### [Prowl](http://prowl.weks.net)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/prowl-growl-client/id320876271?mt=8) ($2.99)

The app itself is ultimately a "dumb client" for sending push notifications to your phone. Prowl is a service used to push arbitrary text to you. There are numerous services in the wild for leveraging it to send you NAGIOS and other alerts from monitoring software, Prey Fetcher exists to push posts, @'s, DMs, and list updates to you, and anything else you're capable of dreaming up.

Answer (score 0):

### [Flashcards Deluxe](http://orangeorapple.com/Flashcards/Default.aspx)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/flashcards-deluxe/id307840670?mt=8) (USD 3.99)

Not perfect, but possibly the best SRS app on the (U.S.) App Store.

Answer (score 0):

### Epic Win

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/app/epicwin/id372927221?mt=8) ($2.99)

This is a great app for task management. It's a lot more fun than Things, although not as feature-full it combines a To Do list app with an RPG. Beautifully designed and useful.

Answer (score 0):

### iGmail

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/igmail-when-gmail-meets-iphone/id328800112?mt=8) (free)

Just a browser wrapper to use **gmail** easily and quickly. I find this much better than regular Maill.app - too bad it doesn't have an offline version thus being slow and not as much reliable.

Comment: What is wrong with the regular Mail.app? Having Gmail setup through Exchange (m.google.com) works nice with push e-mail, contacts and calendar. Only labels do not work as natural as the web interface.

Comment: @bouke **search** doesn't work as good as gmail on mail.app - that's about **half** of my gmail usage, which is a big problem. - for the record, I do use it as you've pointed, and I keep hoping the search will get better.

Comment: searching is indeed a no-go with the Mail.app setup. I would also like to see that fixed.

Answer (score 0):

### [Qik](http://qik.com/)

First and best real time video streaming on iPhone. 'nof said.

Answer (score 0):

### [Longitude](http://www.technivations.com/apps/longitude)

(Available in Cydia; jailbroken only)

Automatically feed your location into Google Latitude.

Comment: Doesn't googles own [Latitude](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-latitude/id306586497?mt=8) cover this?

Comment: @deiga only on iOS 4 devices with multitasking enabled (iPhone 3G doesn't have it by default). Longitude works on any iOS 3 device, you can set the refresh rate up to 4 hours and I'd bet it consumes less memory and battery.

Answer (score 0):

### [Kirikae](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-kirikae/)

Brings multi-tasking to iOS 3 way before iOS 4 was born. It actually works even better than iOS 4, from my opinion, because it doesn't leave every app open (which can bring batter down quickly) but it does let you configure if you want to do that per app basis. In other words, you can configure which app you want to automatically leave in background.

Comment: As of 2018, background apps aren't just left open all the time (at least in more recent versions). They're suspended, and if the system runs out of memory, silently killed.

Answer (score 0):

### [Ninjawords](http://ninjawords.com/info/about/)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/app/ninjawords-dictionary/id316377359?mt=8) ($1.99)

A dictionary, to put it simply. It uses definitions from Wiktionary, which I find both more concise & more helpful than those of Dictionary.com, for instance. More importantly though, it's got a fast, lean & intuitive interface. No superfluous features, but I never find myself missing any functionality. It's a joy to use, unlike any other dictionary app I've tried.

Answer (score 0):

### [Textie](http://textie.me/)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/au/app/textie-messaging-beautiful/id353912946?mt=8) (free, $1.99 to remove ads)

Textie provides free messaging between iOS devices a la SMS. If Textie isn't installed on the recipient device, the service will route the message to SMS on many US mobiles, & to email in every other case. Replies are delivered to Textie on the original sending device with push notifications. The icing on the cake is the slick, minimal interface.

WhatsApp is already on this list, but not only does it not integrate with SMS or email, but I've always found it to have extremely variable latency, from a couple of seconds to two days. Textie's latency has never exceeded twenty seconds for me.

Comment: So...how is this better than iMessage? It also routes to SMS if iMessage isn't available. (Plus, it's end-to-end encrypted!)

Answer (score 0):

### [ShopShop](http://nschum.de/apps/ShopShop/)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/shopshop-shopping-list/id288350249?mt=8) (free)

I feel like a bit of a dork for posting this but I find it quite useful and simple.  It's just a list app.  It keeps a repository of all entries you make so you can quickly add them back the next time you need it.  Make a grocery list and check them off.  The next time you won't have to type out items you've already used, just add them to a new list from the remembered items.

Answer (score 0):

## [MobileRSS Pro ~ Google RSS News Reader](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mobilerss-pro-google-rss-news/id325594202?mt=8)

Pretty self-explanatory.  An RSS reader for Google Reader.  Simple and well-designed.

Answer (score 0):

### [Boxcar](http://boxcar.io/)

[App Store](http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=321493542&mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D6) (Free)

Aggregates notifications from various services including Twitter and Facebook; the killer features of this, for me, are its integration with Buzz, which has no built-in iOS notifications, and Growl, allowing me to send notifications from scripts running on my desktop and get them on my iPod Touch.

Answer (score 0):

### [Papers](http://mekentosj.com/papers/iphone/)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/app/papers/id304655618?mt=8) ($14.99)

Tool for managing academic journal articles. Syncs with the [Mac App](http://mekentosj.com/papers).

Answer (score 0):

### [Site to Phone](http://www.sitetophone.com/)

Bookmarklet that lets you send the current page in your browser to your mobile device of choice.

Answer (score 0):

### [Age Of Zombies](http://www.ageofzombies.com/)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/age-of-zombies/id395627741?mt=8) (USD $2.99)

Pure awesome fun.

Answer (score 0):

### [Posterous](http://posterous.com)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/posterous/id394252521?mt=8) (free)

Post to your posterous.com microblog, especially useful for posting pictures and location on-the-go. Similar to twitter feeds, but a bit nicer to view photo galleries for your viewers. It can be set up to auto-publish to twitter, facebook, tumblr, etc.

Answer (score 0):

### [Notebooks](http://www.alfonsschmid.com/Notebooks/Notebooks_for_iPhone.html)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/notebooks-write-notes-manage/id297571751?mt=8) ($5.99)

Another note taking system. Can also display HTML and RTF files, and you can sort notes into a hierarchy of notebooks.

Answer (score 0):

### [TechNews](http://allendunahoo.com)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/technews/id471305727?ls=1&mt=8)

This is errr... my app, but I couldn't find any rules on this one.
Anyway, it is a really cool news app about Apple and other related stuff.

Answer (score 0):

### [Grocery IQ](http://www.groceryiq.com/)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/grocery-iq/id290591617?mt=8)

A great grocery list management app. Can be shared across users - so for example, I can add items at home on my iPad and the list is synchronized to my wife's iPhone while she shops.

Answer (score 0):

### [Twitterific for Twitter](http://iconfactory.com/software/twitterrific)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/twitterrific-for-twitter/id359914600?mt=8)

A great Twitter client for iPhone and iPad. Free/ad version and paid versions available.

Answer (score 0):

## [Zite](http://zite.com/)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/zite/id419752338) (free)

Zite is a free personalized magazine for your iPhone that automatically learns what you like and gets smarter every time you use it.

Answer (score 0):

## [Talkatone](http://www.talkatone.com/)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/talkatone-free-calls-sms-texting/id397648381?mt=8) (free)

Allows you to make completely free phone calls using your Google Voice account.

Answer (score 0):

### [Opera Mini](http://www.opera.com/mobile/)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/opera-mini-web-browser/id363729560) (free)

Opera Mini offers the fastest, most cost-efficient web-browsing experience for your iOS device today.

Of course, if data limits/costs are of no concern, just use Safari for the most beautiful browsing experience on iOS — but Opera Mini is perfect for travelling abroad, to keep data roaming costs to a minimum, or when you’re stuck with a slow connection.

Answer (score -1):

### [LogMeIn Ignition](https://secure.logmein.com/products/ignition/)

[App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/en/app/logmein-ignition/id299616801) ($29.99)

Remote control in which you can see the screen with free subscriptions and desktop versions. iPhone app costs quite a bit, but it's the best remote control for iPhone I've seem, and probably the first too. Works over web or within same intranet wifi.

Answer (score -1):

### [TomTom](http://www.tomtom.com/en_gb/products/mobile-navigation/)

Car navigation with full offline maps for probably every country out there. TomTom is well known for their own car navigation GPS's, but this version for iphone can become very handy from times to times where you don't have one proper device.

Comment: Down-voted because TomTom takes your location and speed data and sells it to the Police. The Police then use it to set up speed traps or to use against you should you decide to take a ticket to court.

Comment: @Bryson I wouldn't put my hand on fire for any company, but you're making a very bold allegation there. Can you cite some sources or make some sense of this? Plus it's not like any of those GPS apps are so reliable to be taken as an evidence in court, I'd guess.

Comment: Engadget had an article a couple weeks ago about it. TomTom sold data to the Dutch police force, who then used it to set up speed traps based on the speed and location data. TomTom said they were shocked that the police would do this. I'm not sure what else they expected them to use it for when they sold it to them. http://www.engadget.com/2011/04/27/tomtom-user-data-sold-to-danish-police-used-to-determine-ideal/

Comment: @Bryson I got the wrong impression from what you've said, and I think maybe you got the wrong impression from what happened too. It doesn't take *your location to the police*, it takes **anonymous** locations and speed data to them, and they retracted from doing it again because it was being used for speed traps. Again, I don't think they're that innocent, no big company is, but they also are very cautious on shooting their own feet like that. So, no, I don't think I agree with you on your worrying or protest - but thanks for bringing it up. It was an interesting view of the company.

Answer (score -1):

### [Zapd](http://www.zapd.com)

Great app to publish entire websites from your iPhone in a few clicks.