# Great Apple (first and third-party) accessories or peripherals

Tags: iphone, ipad, mac, hardware-recommendation

List your favorite accessory (or peripheral) for your Apple hardware.

**Rules**

- Limit to one accessory per answer.
- Add a short description for the accessory.
- Add a link to the website in the name of the accessory if possible .
- Use **## accessoryName (price)** for citing the accessory name.
- Check for dupes.

Only Mac OS X and iOS compatible accessories.

Some people don't like these questions. If you are one of them please look the other way. [These types of questions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/706/iphone-apps-you-cant-live-without) have been successful in the past.

Comment: Shopping questions are off topic.

Comment: This one is a hardware shopping recommendation. Which are all off topic as per the FAQ.

Comment: @Mark Shopping recommendations are of the form "I'm looking to buy an X, is product Y or product Z better?" or "What is the best product to do X?". The reason why those are bad is because they are, among other things, too localized. This question is of a different form, and has broader appeal, so I think it's OK.

Comment: If anybody who downvoted this question reads this, it'd be great if you un-downvoted it if you did so only because you felt it was "not allowed per the FAQ". If you have a legitimate reason, then don't listen to me if you still think it should remain downvoted :).

Comment: Given how broad a net this question casts, I'm amazed that almost a year later, there are only 9 answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [ScanSnap S1300](http://www.fujitsu.com/us/services/computing/peripherals/scanners/scansnap/s1300.html)

Fujitsu ScanSnap S1300 ([$254 on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003990GMQ))

[image]

The Fujitsu ScanSnap S1300 is a document scanner capable of scanning both sides of a page in color or black & white. The scanner software is usually able to correct documents that did not feed perfectly straight to produce straight output. The software then produces a searchable PDF file that can be indexed by Spotlight on Mac OS X.

Comment: "searchable PDF" as in it does OCR?

Comment: @DanielL Indeed

Answer (score 4):

### [Smart Cover](http://www.apple.com/ipad/smart-cover/)

Apple's Smart Cover for iPad 2 ($39 for Polyurethane, $69 for leather)

[image: smart cover]

> The Smart Cover and iPad 2 were made for each other. Literally. Built-in magnets draw the Smart Cover to iPad for a perfect fit that not only protects, but also wakes up, stands up, and brightens up your iPad. That’s not just smart. It’s genius.

Answer (score 4):

### [Magic Trackpad](http://www.apple.com/magictrackpad/)

Apple's Magic Trackpad ($59)

[image: Magic Trackpad]

> Desktop users, your time has come. The new Magic Trackpad is the first Multi-Touch trackpad designed to work with your Mac desktop computer. It uses the same Multi-Touch technology you love on the MacBook Pro. And it supports a full set of gestures, giving you a whole new way to control and interact with what’s on your screen. Swiping through pages online feels just like flipping through pages in a book or magazine. And inertial scrolling makes moving up and down a page more natural than ever. Magic Trackpad connects to your Mac via Bluetooth wireless technology. Use it in place of a mouse or in conjunction with one on any Mac computer — even a notebook.

Answer (score 2):

### [MX Revolution](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/428/130)

Logitech MX Revolution (discontinued). Successor is [Logitech Performance Mouse MX](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/mice-pointers/mice/devices/5845) ($79)

[image]

The Logitech MX Revolution is a wireless mouse with a USB receiver. Its contoured design fits comfortably in the palm of your hand. The mouse is completely functional with Mac OS X, and the included software allows for the redefinition of almost any function to the various buttons.

Answer (score 1):

### [TuneBase Direct](https://web.archive.org/web/20160305090216/http://www.belkin.com/IWCatProductPage.process?Product_Id=492842)

Belkin's TuneBase Direct ($69)

[image]
<sub>(source: [belkin.com](https://www.belkin.com/images/TuneBaseDirect.jpg))</sub>

The Belkin TuneBase Direct plugs into the cigarette lighter of your vehicle and allows convenient access to an iPhone or iPod while charging it. The TuneBase direct also includes a cable to connect to the 3.5mm input jack to your vehicle's stereo. The button in front of the dock connector allows for easy play/pause, forward, and backward controls for iPod playback.

Comment: The picture on Belkin's site, as compared to this picture, makes it look like the stand is flexibly tense? Meaning you can bend it to a certain extent and it will keep enough tension to act as a mount?

Comment: @VxJasonxV Yeah, but it's not really long enough to do interesting things with, but it does allow you to be more *flexible* in the positioning of your device.

Comment: My biggest problem with using this is that my Cigarette Lighter is recessed under my stereo deck and all the dashboard buttons. So I think, if the neck is long enough, the phone will be low, but may still work out. I'll have to check this out soon.

Comment: @VxJasonxV Can you post a picture of its position?

Comment: Not in a comment I can't. This link will have to do: [Honda Civic Interior](http://i.imgur.com/GN99v.jpg) Note how it's recessed behind the gear/handbrake. (And if anyone's interested, no, this is not actually a picture of my actual car, nor is this my picture.)

Answer (score 0):

### [Razer Naga](http://store.razerzone.com/store/razerusa/en_US/pd/productID.169418900)

Mac-compatible gaming/general use mouse. [$70](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002MPPRPO)

A mouse. With 17 buttons. That isn't a typo. Seventeen.

Mac and PC users can configure them and create macros. Supports automatic profile switching based on app.

It's really comfy.

http://www.sempercog.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/naga.png

Answer (score 0):

### [Griffin Elevator](https://store.griffintechnology.com/desktop/elevator)

Griffin Elevator ($39.99)
[image]

> **Lift your laptop to a comfortable viewing height and reclaim your
>   desktop.**
>
> Elevator's sturdy brushed aluminum and
>   minimal design go great with any desk
>   decor.
>
> Elevator holds your portable computer
>   safely and securely at just the right
>   height to match external monitors -
>   and to save your aching neck.
>
> Elevator conforms to health and safety
>   standards, making your laptop safer
>   and more comfortable to use all day
>   long. Healthycomputing.com, the
>   premier source for office ergonomics,
>   recommends positioning the top of your
>   screen level with your eyes and
>   sitting at least an arm's length
>   distance from the screen. Both of
>   these key ergonomic standards are made
>   possible using Elevator with an
>   external keyboard.

Comment: This laptop stand is really poorly designed and overpriced. I'd recommend getting a height adjustable Adam Hall stand for about half the price: http://www.adamhall.com/en/ah_Stands_SLT001E_-_Laptop_Stand.html

Answer (score 0):

## [Griffin PowerMate](https://store.griffintechnology.com/powermate-1)

Griffin PowerMate USB Controller ($45)

The PowerMate can be set up such that the anti-clockwise/clockwise rotation of the input device causes scrolling up and down of a web page in a web browser when it is in focus on the desktop, or the system audio volume when it is not. The status LED on the underside of the PowerMate could be set up as an indicator of resource usage, i.e. CPU usage, when the input device is not in use, and when in use the LED could be set to indicate volume level by LED brightness.

The configuration software allows for custom configuration for each software application. A video editing program can use the PowerMate to scroll through the timeline. Or it can be configured to scroll through your browser page history and push to refresh. It would also work well for breakout-style games.

Answer (score 0):

### [Belkin Headphone Adapter](https://www.belkin.com/IWCatProductPage.process?Product_Id=496831)

A short extension cable that acts identically to the built-in button on Apple's headphones, though it lacks the microphone. ($20)

[image: Belkin Headphone Adapter Picture]

The Belkin Headphone Adapter enables you to turn any pair of headphones, or other Stereo Audio Cable, into one that allows you to manage your iOS device in the same way you would with Apple's stock headphones. You have volume control buttons, as well as a middle click that allows you to;

- (1-click) play/pause,
- (2-clicks) skip forward, and
- (3-clicks) skip backwards with your media.

We use this in order to facilitate media playback in our car, which only has an 1/8" Stereo Line-In jack. We start whatever media we're going to listen to beforehand, then while in the car, we plug the cable in and start driving. Then, it is trivial to pause or skip songs when desired.

Answer (score 0):

[Henge Docks](http://hengedocks.com/index.html)

Quickly, easily and cleanly incorporate your MacBook computer into a desktop setup or your home theater system, so you get the best features of a laptop, desktop and media center PC all from one computer. Henge Docks patent-pending design doesn’t require any hardware, software or settings changes to your Apple Mac.

[image]

Comment: Seem to be Unibody only.