# Are there any cool free 3D games on the OS X platform?

Tags: games

I've been recently playing [Urban Terror](http://www.urbanterror.info/news/home/), which is a multiplayer FPS game built on Quake 3 engine, and runs across Mac/Linux/Windows. Are there more such games that are

- free
- run on immersive 3D engine [not a Flash/HTML5 game]
- belong to action-adventure/RPG/RTS/[insert your favorite] genre
- possibly multi-platform [not must-have but a nice-to-have]

Thanks!

Comment: This is an awfully subjective (and a list question). Same rules as other list questions apply here. (See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82/os-x-applications-you-cant-live-without for example)

Comment: @Chealion While I agree that it's a list question and following those rules would be nice, is it really subjective? Seems to me one could objectively list all free, 3D-engine driven OS X games. The only possible subjective aspect is determining a genre…

Comment: @Chealion ignoring, of course, the big argument between "free" as in beer and "free" as in open-source. :) But that could be fixed with clarification from @rubayeet.

Comment: @Chealion - I admit the question is subjective in the sense that it's tricky to distinguish a single correct for such questions. However, my curiosity is genuine. I'm not just trying to list out a few apps(that I know of) in the answer thread(as in the question you linked). I'm trying to find out such games with the help of the community.

Comment: @ghoppe: Cool is subjective - the community here has said they want to allow list style questions like this - I just wanted to reiterate the rules that help make the list question on Apple.SE worthwhile (and allow the OP to add them to the question)

Comment: see also: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/682/great-os-x-games

Answer (score 2):

No discussion of free FPS games on the Macintosh can be complete without a link to **[Aleph One](http://marathon.sourceforge.net/)**.

And of course, there's that recruiting tool, America's Army. [Version 2.5 was available for Mac OS X](http://www.macgamefiles.com/detail.php?item=17749). I guess version 3 isn't being developed for Macintosh yet…